# Why would someone upload many iptables files during a security breach and are they a cause for concern?

Tags: file-upload, iptables

My workplace had multiple unauthorized access security failures over the last month. Since then, most computers have been scrubbed and user accounts purged. Data was recovered from offsite backups and the holes have apparently been plugged.

I am not IT and am not entirely familiar with what happened but since the entire security team was fired, the rumours are that it was a simple SQL injection attack. I am not clear on how much access they got. Our systems are a mix of Windows 7/RHEL 6.7/BOSS 6.0

Now after restore, I find that several hundred iptables files have been added to my user storage. They were added last month during the breach and IT told me they are not a cause for concern and won't do any harm. Also, I have never accessed any personal sites from those machines and all passwords and biometrics have been reset.

Here is the contents of just one of the files: http://pastebin.com/DVXnQmV0

My question is why would someone do this and should I be worried?

Comment: Can you explain what the files are actually for? Meaning, the text you pasted was the printout of a set of rules. They might just be a means to audit iptables rules that are in effect. They would almost certainly not be an attempt to override firewall rules since it would be hard to accomplish that with the text you showed.  Are the files dated sequentially, like every day at 4am for a period of time? Why they would even be placed in your user account directory at all is another mystery, though.

Comment: I wouldn't fire the security team for a simple SQL injection. I'd fire the developers of that software - holes like that simply shouldn't exist anymore! They do though...

Comment: @JeffMeden It's very weird. The files are titles CM3D2.YASD.[time].[date].[hex no.].

Comment: 100% agreed with Matthew. Firing the whole security team over a hole created by insecure developers is insane.

Comment: @Matthew Our security system is handled by Cyberroam and those guys spread the rumour.

Comment: @RaunakS If your security team allowed the vulnerable code to go through by not training developers, it's both the developers and the infosec team that is at fault. If the security team enforced rules that were not followed by the developers and/or code reviewers, then the developers / code reviewers are at fault. No matter which way you look at it, the fault mainly lies with the developers. Firing your whole IT Security team over this shows that your company is looking for someone to blame, rather than discover what *truly* happened. And it likely means they don't actually care about infosec.

Comment: I understand. I mean everyone was scared about the breach and the sec team people got scapegoated. They were blamed by almost everyone for not detecting the intrusion for a fortnight. I am neutral on the matter.

Comment: It depends on how it happened.  If management secretly purchased a 3rd party product an implement it, then they are scape goating security.  If you have on site developer, then the security team should have audited the code in a DMZ and caught the error.  If the security team said **NO** but management over-rode it, then its managements fault.  Yes, these things happen in real life, and only generous amounts of CYA will save you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They obviously changed the rules to stop the hackers

**Chain DENYIN**  sole purpose is a blacklist of ip addresses.
Obviously, this list was derived from the log files as the sources of the attack.

**Chain DENYOUT**
Clearly is meant to log and drop outbound connections to the attacking list of IP addresses.  Just in case they are still in the system.

**Chain INVALID** 
Is for packets that shouldn't occur on your network.

The rules **look** good, but as you said this is only part of your rules.  A hacker would not put rules in place to block themselves as that is self defeating.

Whoever wrote these rules knows something about security.  However, they should be using **ipset** in combination with IP tables for efficiency as excessive iptables rules use extra CPU cycles.  However, they were smart enough to divide the traffic into chains to at least make a bit easier on themselves.

Yet with an INPUT policy of drop, and making the last rule in INPUT drop just incase many of the other drops are un-necessary.  Except the last 3 log lines ALL of LOGDROPIN is redundant(538-555).

The fact that there are no subnets like (/30) or whatever would make it easy for a hacker to +1 their IP address and **possible** break in again.  Some IP you may not be able to subnet mask, but many of them you can.  If it turns out they used an amazon,google,microsoft cloud server, you can't block all of amazon,google,microsoft it doesn't make sense.

I am not auditing ALL your rules because I am not getting paid, however I have given you some good general info.  Don't post all of your rules, for me anyway, I am not doing a free audit of your whole system.